# Is there an option to execute javascript file only on plugin activation

Tags: php, plugin-development, hooks

I'm creating a custom plugin for WordPress and I'm trying to execute `javascript` file only once right after plugin activations.

I'm using `register_activation_hook()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` to execute file only once when the plugin is activated.

There are no errors in the code since the `javascript` code works well if it is called outside the `register_activation_hook()`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'full_install' );
function full_install() {
    function rest_api() {
        wp_enqueue_script('activation_data_api', plugins_url('assets/js/activation_data_api.js', __FILE__));
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rest_api' );
}
```

In the end, the plugin needs to execute `javascript` file only once right after activation.

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook#Process_Flow).

Comment: @SallyCJ I've tried with that, but probably I've done something wrong because it didn't work. Can you please show me on my example how can I do that?

Comment: Well, you've already got it correct now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'rest_api_hook' );

/**
 * Runs only when the plugin is activated.
 */
function rest_api_hook() {

    /* Create data */
    set_transient( 'rest_api', true, 5 );
}

/* Add notice */
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'rest_api_hook_exec' );

/**
 * Rest API Notice on Activation.
 */
function rest_api_hook_exec() {

    /* Check transient, if is available display notice */
    if( get_transient( 'rest_api' ) ) { 

        // Execute script
        wp_enqueue_script('activation_data_api', plugins_url('assets/js/activation_data_api.js', __FILE__));

        // Delete script after executing
        delete_transient( 'rest_api' );
    }
}
```